# Can't interact with frameless, transparent BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

The main window of my electron app doesn't respond to any actions, as if it has a transparent overlay. All elements are rendered, but I can't press any button or write in input.

This happens only on Windows and only when the `frame` is set to `false`

```
win = new BrowserWindow({ frame: false, transparent: true, resizable: true, alwaysOnTop: true, width: 400, height: 130 });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You might need to provide more context. Also what's your electron version?

Comment: Almost sounds like you have `-webkit-app-region: drag;` set in your CSS somewhere. Try setting `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` to the navbar or some other element on your page to see if that element allows interaction (button-click or text-input).

Comment: Additionally, check the [limitations](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md#limitations) of using `transparent`. Cannot click through the transparent area & `resizable` is not supported.

Comment: Thanks Neil!! it was the `-webkit-app-region: drag;`. You should post it as the answer.

Comment: I found this github [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1354) about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Neil suggested in the comments above, the problem was caused by a  `-webkit-app-region: drag;`  rule on a container div. 
Thanks!